# Breaking VBA code docmd.runsql into seperate lines

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```
 DoCmd.RunSQL _
"INSERT INTO dbo_TimerTable ( Minutes, ClientFirst, ClientLast, StartTime, EndTime, Reason, UserInitials, ClientID )" & _
"SELECT 30 AS Expr1, [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![FirstName] AS Expr2, [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![LastName] AS Expr3, Now() AS Expr4, Now() AS Expr5, "Letter to Client" AS Expr6, "MC" AS Expr7, [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![ClientID] AS Expr8""
```

I am trying to break this runsql command into separate lines. I currently have this command running through a while loop on a record set. I cannot seem to get this sql to work correctly. Any help is appreciated and thank you!

EDIT:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO dbo_TimerTable " _
& "(Minutes, ClientFirst, ClientLast, StartTime, EndTime, Reason, UserInitials, ClientID ) VALUES" _
& "( 30, & [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![FirstName], & [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![LastName], Now(), Now(), " & "Letter to Client", "MC", [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![ClientID]
```

I changed my code to this now and i just need help with the formating of the values, i am getting stuck on when to put & for the variables. Thanks again!

Comment: This is just asking for SQL Injection.  In any case you need to separate the parts coming from your Access form from the parts that you have hard-coded, like this:  "( 30," & [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![FirstName] & "," &...

Answer (score 0):

It is only 1 statement.  You have put the names of the controls in literally, needs to be like so `"30 as e1, " & [Forms]![Daily Appearance Sheet Verified]![FirstName] & "......` also 'letter to client' and 'MC'  You could just used `VALUES (` rather than the select part

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am almost there in getting the formatting correct now. I just changed my code above if you are able to help at all. Thanks again!